# Wrong projection high quality shapefile for the coastline of Helsinki region (Finland)

Tags: shapefile, r, coordinate-system, finland

I did some spatial interpolations in R and I need a support for those.

Looking for shapefiles online the best I could find was [image: this] and it looks really horrible, the same area in `ggplot` looks like [image: this]. I spent a lot of time on this, to no avail, I found shapefiles with any kind of informations, but nothing that has a good definition of the shore.

EDIT my code

```
rm(list=ls())
setwd("C:/Users/irene/Desktop/FIN_adm")
graphics.off()
Finland <- readOGR(".","FIN_adm0")
#OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
#Source: ".", layer: "FIN_adm0"
#with 1 features and 70 fields
#Feature type: wkbMultiPolygon with 2 dimensions

#prj file says GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]

setwd("C:/tesi/Rtoshiba/dati/3 downtown")
data44 <- read.table("ch44.txt", header=T)
head(data44)
locations<-unique(cbind(data44[,1], data44[,2]))
#plot(locations)

media.stat44=vector(length=109)
media.rssi44=vector(length=109)

for (i in 1:109){
  temp<-data44[data44[,1]==locations[i,1] & data44[,2]==locations[i,2],]#location i
  media.stat44[i]<-mean(temp$stat)
  media.rssi44[i]<-mean(temp$rssi)
}

temp44<-cbind(locations, media.stat44)
xy <- temp44[,1:2]
df44 <- as.data.frame(temp44[,-1:-2])
SPDF44 <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=xy, data=df44)


bbox = c(min(data44$lon), min(data44$lat),
         max(data44$lon), max(data44$lat))

predgrid <- expand.grid(lon=seq(from=bbox[1], to=bbox[3], length.out=400), 
                        lat=seq(from=bbox[2], to=bbox[4], length.out=400))

aa<-as.data.frame(rep(NA,160000))  
dimnames(aa)[[2]]<-"stat"
loc<-SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=predgrid, data=aa)

ciccia44<-as.data.frame(df44)
dimnames(ciccia44)[[2]]<-"stat"
SPDFgri44<-SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=locations, data=ciccia44)

stima44 <- idw(stat~1, SPDFgri44, loc, idp = 1.0, debug.level = 1)

library(raster)
rast44 <- raster(stima44)

f44<-as.data.frame(stima44)
# create spatial points data frame
spg <- f44
coordinates(spg) <- ~ x + y
# coerce to SpatialPixelsDataFrame
gridded(spg) <- TRUE
# coerce to raster
rasterDF <- raster(spg)
rasterDF
x11()
plot(rasterDF)

# setwd("C:/tesi/GIS_data/FIN_adm")
# #setwd("C:/Users/irene/Desktop/fi")
# 
# Finland <- readShapePoly("FIN_adm1.shp")
# Finland
# #str(Finland)
# unique(Finland@data$VARNAME_1)
# Finland <- Finland[Finland$VARNAME_1 == "Etelä-Suomen lääni|Södra Finlands län",]
vv<-fortify(Finland)

#prova subset sia giusto
#x11()
#plot(vv[,1], vv[,2])

projection(Finland) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs")

elevation.sub <- crop(rasterDF, extent(Finland))

elevation.sub <- mask(elevation.sub, Finland)

x11()
plot(elevation.sub)
plot(Finland, add = TRUE)
```

I downloaded (between others) the shapefile suggested in the answer, selected the tile I am interested in getting [image: this result]
Code I used:

```
Finland2 <- readOGR(".","helsinki")


class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 1331 
extent      : 2704914, 2905588, 8392151, 8516090  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 3
names       : error, tile_x, tile_y 
min values  :     0,    227,    283 
max values  :     0,    228,    284 
unique(Finland2@data$tile_x)
unique(Finland2@data$tile_y)
```

I select the tile I am interested into

```
Finland3 <- Finland2 [Finland2$tile_x == 227 &  Finland2$tile_y == 284, ]
```

And project it

```
Finland3<-spTransform(Finland3, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs+ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 "))

x11()
plot(Finland3)
```

Is the change of projection wrong? Because when I write `Finland3` I get:

```
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 742 
extent      : 24.29866, 25.20134, 60.23717, 60.68294  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 3
names       : error, tile_x, tile_y 
min values  :     0,    227,    284 
max values  :     0,    227,    284
```

This map shows the tile I want, but the geocoding is wrong at least north-south.

QUESTION:is the projection wrong?????

EDIT AFTER NEW SHP
I still get wrong coordinates, this [image: tile] has extent (24.29866, 25.20134, 60.23717, 60.68294)  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) and if I check these on google maps they are not overlapping, but I need them to overlap my raster when I import I just do:

```
aa<-readOGR(".", "helsinki_wgs84")
unique(aa@data$tile_x)
unique(aa@data$tile_y)
aa3 <- aa [aa$tile_x == 227 &  aa$tile_y == 284, ]
Finland3<-spTransform(aa3, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs+ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 "))

x11()
plot(Finland3)
```

Comment: That is where I got the shapefile. I'll post my code, maybe I am doing something wrong

Comment: Large Scale Data for Helsinki http://kartat.kapsi.fi/ includes coastline datasets

Comment: I am looking at it (it is taking a bit since I don't speak Finnish), in case I upload my code, in case you want to give a look, it is just an IDW interpolation, but I want to crop the raster to the border of the shapefile.

Comment: Those diva shapes are really poor quality. Can you give the download path to the shape you are using now? I guess it would be much easier to view and cut the data in QGIS.

Comment: @AndreJoost I tried to use those suggested by Kevin R Dyke to no better result (see my answer). I really do not feel confident and miss guidelines, if you could help that would be awesome, really.

Comment: Perhaps you should clean up your question. The Fin_adm from diva shapefile are very very simplified, and therefore useless for you. The data mentioned by Kevin comes in mercator projection (maybe the special one Google uses), and the Openstreetmap coastline I suggested can be downlaoded in WGS84 lat/lon. This fits to your first datasource, but with better resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end I used the shapefile from [the National Land survey of Finland](http://kartat.kapsi.fi) even though not perfect, they seemed to be of a higher quality

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://metro.teczno.com/#helsinki) set of extracts from OSM data may be what you're looking for. In particular, [this](http://osm-extracted-metros.s3.amazonaws.com/helsinki.coastline.zip) shapefile of the coastline around Helsinki.

Comment: If the extent is to small, take the worldwide version: http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/coastlines

Comment: The extent is ok, but I have a projection problem, I'll clear up the question.

Comment: I realised I should have posted another question with this, therefore I did it

Comment: @Kevin R Dyke can the .prj be possibly wrong?

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem with the coordinates. Maybe it's the somewhat non-standard projection definition? Try [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8550761/helsinki_wgs84.zip) version, which I quickly made with ogr2ogr. It's the same shapefile, but it's using unprojected WGS84 coordinates. They seem right to me, so it may be worth starting with that and reprojecting as you see fit.

Comment: @KevinRDyke it still does not work for me. I have no idea why, can you check my code? Maybe I a somehow importing it wrongly. I'll add another picture in the question

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with R, so I can't help with that.