# projection conversion from mercator to google maps format

Tags: r, coordinate-system, ggmap

Is this

```
spTransform(Finland3, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs+ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 "))
```

the right way to project a shapefile with this projection

```
coord. ref. : +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

to plot it in `ggmap` on top of a Google map raster?

therefore looking like

```
+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

Comment: Please any help is welcome. I need this for my thesis and my tutor is unable to help me in this and I don't know anybody to whom I could ask for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @user30184 the kapsi repository had what I needed, it can be found at [this link](http://kartat.kapsi.fi)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the `gmap()` functionality offered by the `dismo` package instead of `ggmap`? You can download Google maps of type 'satellite', 'terrain', 'roadmap' and 'hybrid' there as well. The advantage is that the thus aquired maps are instantly available as objects of class 'RasterLayer' or 'RasterStack', holding a defined spatial information.

Setting `gmap(..., lonlat = TRUE)`, you can then use

```
spTransform(Finland3, CRS(proj4string(map)))
```

as mentioned above to reproject your Finland shapefile to EPSG:4326 and combine the resulting data sets in one plot.

Comment: GIS is really not my field I am really sorry if I sound stupid or pathetic. I need to plot my interpolation and/or spatial prediction which I did in R on top of the map. To do this I transformed the dataframe to a raster and would like to clip it so that "it does not get out of the coast". To attain this I understood that I have to us a shapefile, and did this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103738/wrong-projection-high-quality-shapefile-for-the-coastline-of-helsinki-region-fi what I want is to get the first image on top of the second (see the dark shade) but I need a high quality shp.

Comment: Am I doing it all wrong?

Comment: If you solve your other problems you will meet a 200 m shift in your data because your EPSG:239x definitions are missing the +towgs84 parameters. Here is a good example of 2393 `KKJ / Finland Uniform Coordinate System
<2393> +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=27 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-96.062,-82.428,-121.753,4.801,0.345,-1.376,1.496 +units=m +no_defs  <>`

Comment: Best source for high quality data is the National Land Survey of Finland and the Kapsi repository. However, coastline is made in a tricky way and it must be combined from several feature classes. Would sea polygons suit for your purpose?